# How to access variable value in vscode extension API

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am working on a custom vscode extension and creating a hover provider. Say I have a json file example.json:

```
{
 exampleOne: ["one", "two"]
}
```

and exampleProxy.js:

```
import exampleMap from "./example.json"

export const ExampleObject = exampleMap;
```

And then in various js files in the project imports like"

```
import { ExampleObject } from "../exampleProxy.js";

const varValue = ExampleObject.exampleOne;
```

In my hover provider I want to get the actual value associated with that object key when the user hovers over the key. So like when user hovers over "exampleOne" in the above example I will get ["one", "two"]. How do I do that?

Heres my hover provider so far:

```
    vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider(
        'javascript',
        new (class implements vscode.HoverProvider {
            provideHover(
                _document: vscode.TextDocument,
                _position: vscode.Position,
                _token: vscode.CancellationToken
            ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Hover> {
                const range = _document.getWordRangeAtPosition(_position, /(?<=ExampleObject\.)\w+/);
                if (!range) {
                    return;
                }
                const word = _document.getText(range);
                console.log('word', word);
            
            }
        })()
    );
```

I can get the name of the key like "exampleOne" but how can i get the value it resolves to?